# Run powershell script on 2003 server

Tags: powershell

I have powershell installed on my windows 8 PC, can I connect to remote 2003 server via powershell with out installing powershell on windows 2003 server? and run powershell commands?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is NO.
You can from you PC query some information of remote computer using WMI ( `get-wmiobject` cmdlet ) or other informations with

```
get-process -computername remotecomputername
```

or

```
get-service -computername remotecomputername
```

and at the moment I can't remember other cmdlets not requiring remote powershell installation.